# Are "sex" and "sexus" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, noun, numbers, origin

Are

- [*sex*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsex) (the number 6) or [*sextus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsextus1) (⅙ or ordinal sixth)
  <sup>(From where the English word "sextant" comes.)</sup>

and

- [*sexus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsexus) (sex or gender)

etymologically related?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The gist of [Au101's answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/1480/12) is confirmed by de Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary*.  First, regarding *sex*, in Proto-Italic and Proto-Indo-European, he gives:

> PIt. **seks* 'six', **seks-to-* 'sixth'
>
> PIE *(s)ueks 'six', *uks-ó- 'sixth'.

He notes:

> The PIt. form **seks* has analogically dropped **-w-* from **sweks* by analogy with **septm* 'seven'.

Regarding *sexus*, there is some question as to its origin.  He writes:

> *Secus* seems the more original formation, but it is strange that the older texts only know *sexus*.  The modern meaning of *sectiō* 'division' suggests that *sec/xus* might derive from *secāre* 'to sever', but the morphology remains unclear: does *sexus* go back to an *s*-present **sek-s-* 'to cut up', or was it derived from a form **sek-s-* of the putative *s*-stem underlying *secus*?

He gives the Proto-Italic root of *secāre* as **sekaje/o-*, and the PIE root as *sekh<sub>I</sub>-ie/o, meaning "to cut off".  For *secus*, PIt. is **sekwos* and PIE is *se-kuo, meaning "for/by oneself, separate."

So to summarize, even in PIE, the roots of these two Latin words were different words with distinct meanings – "six" in the case of *sex* and "separate" or "to cut off" in the case of *sexus*.  So though they bear superficial similarities, the Latin words are etymologically unrelated.

Comment: It would seem division or cutting (_secare_) would be related to a number, as numbers are formed by dividing a whole or unit.

Comment: @Geremia Semantics is very tricky in etymological research and **any two words could be hypothetically "linked", depending on the researcher's imagination and resourcefulness**. Nathaniel didn't tell us why there's *u (or *w) in PIE*(s)ueks "six", PIE *uks-o "sixth" - and that's why de Vaan mentions that "The PIt form *seks has analogically dropped *-w- from *sweks by analogy with *septm 'seven'." The presence of this *w in PIE 6 and its absence in "divide" is a big deal.

Answer (score 11):

No, I don't think so, and for this I can actually rely on [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/) which is a fine resource, even if linguistics students are discouraged from using it for their homework.

The entry for the English word 'six' is complete enough:

> Old English *siex*, *six*, *sex*, from Proto-Germanic **sekhs* (source also of Old Saxon and Danish *seks*, Old Norse, Swedish, and Old Frisian *sex*, Middle Dutch *sesse*, Dutch *zes*, Old High German *sehs*, German *sechs*, Gothic *saihs*), **from PIE **s(w)eks* (source also of** Sanskrit *ṣaṣ*, Avestan *kshvash*, Persian *shash*, Greek *hex*, **Latin *sex***, Old Church Slavonic *sesti*, Polish *sześć*, Russian *shesti*, Lithuanian *szeszi*, Old Irish *se*, Welsh *chwech*).
>
> [Source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=six)

And then for 'sex':

> late 14c., "males or females collectively," **from Latin *sexus* "a sex, state of being either male or female, gender," of uncertain origin. "Commonly taken with *seco* as division or 'half' of the race" [Tucker], which would connect it to *secare* "to divide or cut"** (see section (n.)).
>
> [Source](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sex&allowed_in_frame=0)

And for *secare* we can actually cheat and indulge in use of the same resource. The entry for 'section' reads

> late 14c., "intersection of two straight lines; division of a scale;" from Old French *section* or directly from Latin *sectionem* (nominative *sectio*) "a cutting, cutting off, division," noun of action **from past participle stem of *secare* "to cut," from PIE root **sek-* "to cut"** (source also of Old Church Slavonic *seko*, *sešti* "to cut," *se čivo* "ax, hatchet;" Lithuanian *isekti* "to engrave, carve;" Albanian *šate* "mattock;" Old Saxon *segasna*, Old English *sigðe* "scythe;" Old English *secg* "sword," *seax* "knife, short sword;" Old Irish *doescim* "I cut;" Latin *saxum* "rock, stone")

Comment: It would seem division or cutting (_secare_) would be related to a number, as numbers are formed by dividing a whole or unit.

Comment: @Geremia well fractions are, if you want to think about them like that, but integers aren't. They were just phonetically similar words way back when in PIE, but establishing an etymological link takes a lot more than that

Comment: @Geremia Furthermore, there's no real reason why the number six in particular would be chosen.

Comment: Six is half of a dozen.

Comment: @AsimJalis Your logic is not entirely impossible, but requires a base-12 counting system with 6 serving as a divider. But the PIE counting system was 4-base, and that's why the number 8 is grammatically the dual of 4. As it switched to a 10-base, the divider became the number 5, meaning "a full fist or hand". There is clearly a -w- in the first syllable of 6, which might have been original (*weḱs*), with *s-* introduced by analogy from 7. Moreover the second consonant in 6 is the front *ḱ* (affricated to *ts~s* in Satem), while in "cut" it's the back *k* (in Satem as *k*).